# Convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^2+i}{(k+i)^4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How should I determine the convergence or divergence $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{k^2+i}{(k+i)^4}$?

According to the suggestion in the back of the book, I have tried using the Ratio Test, but found it to be inconclusive.
$$\lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left|\frac{\frac{(k+1)^2+i}{(k+1+i)^4}}{\frac{k^2+i}{(k+i)^4}}\right| = \lim_{k \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{(k+1)^2+i}{k^2+i} \cdot \frac{(k+i)^4}{(k+1+i)^4} \right | =1? $$

Comment: Hi :) Prove $\left|\frac{k^2+i}{(k+i)^4}\right|<\frac{c}{k^2}$ for a constant $c$.